# Getting Syntax error Missing '='

Tags: visualforce, soql, formula, process-builder

While creating a formula field in Process builder, I am getting syntax error missing "="

```
BLANKVALUE((IF([nFUSE__Shopping_Report__c].nFUSE__Shopping_Indicator__c = true, 'Bankruptcy Flag','')+ 
IF([nFUSE__Shopping_Report__c].nFUSE__Cart__c  = true, '- Cart Flag','')+  IF([nFUSE__Shopping_Report__c].nFUSE__Limited__c  = true, '- Limited Flag','')+ IF([nFUSE__Shopping_Report__c].nFUSE__Address_Indicator__c = true, '- Address Flag','')+ IF(NOT(ISBLANK([nFUSE__Shopping_Report__c].nFUSE__Fraud_Alert__c )), '- Fraud Flag','')+ IF(NOT(ISBLANK([nFUSE__Shopping_Report__c].nFUSE__Address_Discrepency__c)), '- Address Flag','')+ IF(NOT(ISPICKVAL([nFUSE__Shopping_Report__c].nFUSE__Country__c, '  No Match'), '- Country Flag','')+ IF([nFUSE__Shopping_Report__c].nFUSE__Number_Of_Charge__c >0, '- Charge Detected','')),'No Flags')
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  You should format your formula to make it easier to read and spot the extra/missing equals sign.  Also, a syntax error can also indicate you have an extra/missing comma, or an extra/missing parentheses, so look for that as well.

Comment: @DavidCheng It was a misplaced and missing parentheses. Double the errors for double the fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formatting your formula, I found that near the end, you misplaced a parentheses, because the IF statement is wrong:

```
IF(
    NOT(
        ISPICKVAL(
            [nFUSE__Shopping_Report__c].nFUSE__Country__c, 
            '  No Match'
        ), 
        '- Country Flag', // This is part of the NOT
        ''  // And so is this
    )+ 
    IF(
        [nFUSE__Shopping_Report__c].nFUSE__Number_Of_Charge__c > 0, 
        '- Charge Detected',
        ''
    )
),
```

---

With proper formatting and indentation, at least when you're writing a formula initially, is a smart idea. Here's the mostly fixed version:

```
BLANKVALUE(
    IF([nFUSE__Shopping_Report__c].nFUSE__Shopping_Indicator__c , 
        'Bankruptcy Flag',''
    )+ 
    IF([nFUSE__Shopping_Report__c].nFUSE__Cart__c  , 
        '- Cart Flag',
        ''
    )+ 
    IF([nFUSE__Shopping_Report__c].nFUSE__Limited__c  , 
        '- Limited Flag',
        ''
    )+ 
    IF([nFUSE__Shopping_Report__c].nFUSE__Address_Indicator__c , 
        '- Address Flag',
        ''
    )+ 
    IF(
        NOT(
            ISBLANK(
                [nFUSE__Shopping_Report__c].nFUSE__Fraud_Alert__c 
            )
        ), 
        '- Fraud Flag',
        ''
    )+ 
    IF(
        NOT(
            ISBLANK(
                [nFUSE__Shopping_Report__c].nFUSE__Address_Discrepency__c
            )
        ), 
        '- Address Flag',
        ''
    )+ 
    IF(
        NOT(
            ISPICKVAL(
                [nFUSE__Shopping_Report__c].nFUSE__Country__c, 
                '  No Match'
            )
        ), 
        '- Country Flag',
        ''
    )+ 
    IF(
        [nFUSE__Shopping_Report__c].nFUSE__Number_Of_Charge__c > 0, 
        '- Charge Detected',
        ''
    ),
    'No Flags'
)
```

Also note that `'  No Match'` is likely wrong; strings cannot start or end with blank spaces. I've fixed it above, but watch out for those as well.

The initial `()` pair wrapping the first parameter to BLANKVALUE is superfluous and can be removed.

Finally, checkboxes are already Boolean; you don't need to use `field = true` to check if they're checked.